# How to Delete nodes from HTML in iOS

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, html-parsing

What I am trying to do is to load a webpage into in a UIWebView. The problem is that I need to do some preprocessing on the html before displaying it in the web view.

The UIWebview loadHTMLString is quiet slow when the html is big. I don't need to display the full page therefore i am trying to remove some html nodes before displaying it in the web view to speed up the loading time.

I don't think using regex for that is a wise idea. I checked out NSXMLParser and TFHPPLE but I couldn't find any way to remove nodes from the html tree using an XPath or something.

I know I could do that using Javascript but that won't solve my problem. I also don't have no control on the website so I can't edit in the webpage itself.

Is there something as easy as deleteNodeUsingXPath or something :)

Cheers and thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility solution: do a proxy website which strips out unwanted stuff. The iphone accesses the proxy website URL. The proxy website loads from the original website, strips out unwanted stuff, and replies with the remaining stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [Objective-C-HTML-Parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) that will do what you are looking for. The documentation is thorough, and the implementation is pretty straight-forward.

Basically, you take your HTML string and make an HTMLParser object that you can then manipulate however you want. It is a very powerful library that basically lets you do whatever you want with HTML with easy-to-use Objective-C APIs.

Good luck!